# Regex gives compiler error

Tags: c#, regex

```
<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>
```

Above is the regex which I took from [Remove all empty HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572238/remove-all-empty-html-tags)
and I am trying to use the same below :-

```
string regex= @"<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>";
```

And I get many compile errors like - newline in constant, unrecognized escape sequence on the above line itself.

Could anybody help me by pointing what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `""` for double quotes inside the string:

```
string regex= @"<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have double quotes inside the regexp that need to be quoted.

```
 string regex= @"<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>";
```

should be

```
string regex= @"<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:\u0022[^\u0022]*\u0022|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>";
```

Btw, because of the `<\/\1\s*>` this will only remove balanced tags surrounding space.  It will match `<p> </p>` but not `<img src=bogus onerror=alert(1337)>`.

Even if all you want to do is remove balanced tags around space, be aware that this will not match all such tags.  Specifically, it will not match tags where the tag name varies by case: `<p> </P>`.

Finally, it will not remove transitively empty tags: `<i><b></b></i>` -> `<i></i>`.

Comment: To include double quotes in a verbatim string you need `""`, not `\"`

Comment: @Andrew Cooper, thanks.   Fixed to use escape sequences which should be interpreted by the regex engine.

Comment: I think the poster only wants to remove empty html tags so I think its just right that your img tag is unmatched

Comment: @Mel, quite right.  I think I'll leave the comment there so that noone searching for a tag stripper stumbles across this and thinks it's a good idea.

Comment: I agree. kinda offtopic, just like to point out that it will not match asp tags like <asp:TextBox> or any tag with a namespace either. CDATA tags and html comments won't be matched either. it wont match <p onclick=alert(1)> </p> too. well bottom line, there a lot to improve on.

Comment: @Mel.  Yep.  It Will mangle `<!-- <p "-->"></p>` and `<![[CDATA  <p " ]]> "></p>` pretty badly.  Similarly for non-tag content inside RCDATA and CDATA elements, e.g. `Put your source inside the script element <textarea><script></script></textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

Single double quotes( `"` ) have to be escaped with double double quotes ( `""` ) in verbatim strings.

Try this

```
string regex= @"<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>";
```